# proving that if $f(x)$ odd then $f(0)=0$

Tags: functions

Need to prove that if $f(x)$ is an odd function that defined in the point: $x=0$,

So $f(0)=0$.

I know that odd function is: $f(-x)=-f(x)$

And that $f(x)=0$ is an odd function but dont know how to prove.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the fact that $f(-0)=-f(0)$, and that $-0=0$.

Comment: You say you did not know how to prove. Fine, you had probably never met it before. But did you try to work out for yourself how to prove it. What value stands out as being a good one to try in the only useful equation around: $f(-x)=-f(x)$?

Comment: @almagest - i saw all the answers and still dont know how to prove. yes, i know that it has to be $0$ becuase $-0=0$ but still i dont see any "full" proof without explaninig the zero part.

Comment: There are two quite separate issues here. Understanding, and presenting a good proof. Both are important. But maybe that is wandering off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x=0, f(0)=-f(-0)=-f(0)$, but this is saying that one number is equal to its negative. This is only true for $0$.

$a=-a\implies a=0$

Comment: that i know but how do you prove that?

Comment: That is the proof. We used the fact the $f(0)$ was odd, i.e, $f(0)=-f(-0)$. We then note that $-0=0$, so we can write $-f(-0)$ as $-f(0)$. We then have that $f(0)=-f(0)$. We conclude that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @dave: If you are asking how to prove that $f(0)=-f(0)$, let $a=f(0)$, and so $-a=-f(0).$

$a=-a\implies 2a=0\implies a=0$.

Comment: now i got all the steps thnks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Take that definition you have for an odd function and use the fact that -0=0,  then treat f(0) as a variable to solve for like an algebra equation.

Comment: can you show how?

Answer (score 0):

$$\text {Applying the definition: }\ f(0)=-f(0) ,$$
$$\text {so if}\ f(0) =c≠0 \text{ you would have two different values in x=0, c and -c}$$
$$\text {which is clearly impossible, so you must have }\ f(0)=0$$
$$\text{because for every x in the domain you must have only one f(x)}$$
$$\text{and 0 is the only value that satisfy that relation.}$$

Answer (score -1):

For a odd function,f(-x)=-f(x) 
  For a given value 0 in domain,
  Put x=0,
f(0)=-f(0)
   2f(0)=0
      f(0)= 0